# Differentiate Row Vectors

Tags: linear-algebra

I am trying to compute the function $J: \mathbb{R}^n \to \mathbb{R}:$
$$J(x) = \frac{1}{2}(x,Ax) - (x,b) = \frac{1}{2}x^T Ax - x^T b.$$

If I have done it correctly, $$\frac{\partial J}{\partial x} = \frac{d}{dx}x^T Ax - x^T A \frac{d}{dx} x - \frac{d}{dx}x^T b.$$

Hence I would need to compute the differential of row vectors. But how can I do it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We have $$J(x) = \dfrac12\sum_{i,j} A_{ij}x_ix_j - \sum_{i=1}^Nx_ib_i$$
Hence,
$$\dfrac{dJ(x)}{dx_k} = \dfrac12\sum_{i,j} A_{ij} \dfrac{d(x_ix_j)}{dx_k} - \sum_{i=1}^Nb_i \dfrac{dx_i}{dx_k}$$
We have
$$\dfrac{d(x_ix_j)}{dx_k} = \delta_{ik}x_j + \delta_{jk}x_i \text{ and }\dfrac{dx_i}{dx_k} = \delta_{ik}$$
Hence,
\begin{align}
\dfrac{dJ(x)}{dx_k} & = \dfrac12\sum_{i,j} A_{ij} \left(\delta_{ik}x_j + \delta_{jk}x_i\right) - \sum_{i=1}^Nb_i \delta_{ik}\\
& = \dfrac12 \sum_{j}A_{kj}x_j + \dfrac12\sum_{i}A_{ik}x_i - b_k\\
& = \dfrac12\left((Ax)_k + (A^Tx)_k\right) - b_k
\end{align}
Hence,
$$\dfrac{dJ}{dx} = \dfrac{\left(A+A^T\right)x}2-b$$

Comment: That's helpful, thanks. Oh seems differentiating row vectors are the same, then?

Answer (score 0):

Let us absorb $\frac{1}{2}$ into A, and rewrite the scalar $-x^Tb=-b^Tx$ whose differential is just $-b^T$.
In order to find the [derivative](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fr%C3%A9chet_derivative#Definition) of the first term let us keep the h-linear term in
$$(x+h)^TA(x+h)-x^TAx=(x^T+h^T)A(x+h)-x^TAx\\\approx
h^TAx+x^TAh= (h^TAx)^T+x^TAh=\\x^T(A+A^T)h
$$
Hence the derivative is: $x^T(A+A^T)$. Adding the two: $x^T(A+A^T)-b^T$. Note that it is not a column- but a row-vector (or covector, or dual vector) as indeed expected of a gradient vector.