# How to find the partial derivative of a row vector?

Tags: linear-algebra, multivariable-calculus

If I have $\vec{x} = \begin{pmatrix}x_1\\ x_2\\ \vdots\\ x_n\end{pmatrix}$, how can I find the derivative of $\vec{x}^T$?

This questions comes when I was trying to find the minimum of the inner product of $\vec x$ and $A \vec x$. So I plan to differentiate $(\vec{x}, A\vec{x})$ with respect to $\vec{x}$ and find the zero. I could multiply out $(\vec{x}, A\vec{x})$ and differentiate, but I really wonder if I can do by product rule:

$$\frac{\partial}{\partial \vec x}(\vec{x}, A\vec{x}) = \frac{\partial}{\partial \vec x}(\vec{x}^TA\vec{x}) = \frac{\partial}{\partial \vec x} \vec{x}^T A\vec{x} + \vec{x}^T A \frac{\partial}{\partial \vec x} \vec{x}.$$

If I want to compute the derivative of $\vec x$ with respect to $\vec x$, I would
$$\frac{\partial}{\partial \vec x} \vec{x} =\begin{pmatrix}\frac{\partial}{\partial x_1}  x_1 &\frac{\partial}{\partial x_2}  x_1 & \cdots & \frac{\partial}{\partial x_n}  x_1\\
\frac{\partial}{\partial x_1}  x_2 &\frac{\partial}{\partial x_2}  x_2 & \cdots & \frac{\partial}{\partial x_n}  x_2\\
\vdots & \vdots &\ddots & \vdots\\
\frac{\partial}{\partial x_1} x_n & \frac{\partial}{\partial x_2} x_n & \cdots & \frac{\partial}{\partial x_n}  x_n
\end{pmatrix}
=
\begin{pmatrix}
1 & 0 & \cdots & 0\\
0 & 1 & \cdots & 0\\
\vdots & \vdots &\ddots & \vdots\\
0 & 0 & \cdots & 1\\
\end{pmatrix}
$$

But how can I compute $\frac{\partial}{\partial \vec x} x^T$?

Thank you

Comment: $\frac{d}{dx}x$ is not even proper terminology. What exactly are you asking for, the [Jacobian](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/Jacobian.html)? The Jacobian is just the identity matrix in this case, of course.

Comment: When it is ment as a symbol of differenciation in terms of how x is changes with change of x, than the result should be identity...

Comment: Thank you @MichaelGrant, I want to differentiate the inner product of $x$ and $Ax$ with respect to $x$. I could multiply out and differentiate, but I really wonder if I can do by product rule?

Comment: OP was certainly thinking about something completely different. However, the proper formalization of the question and a bit of knowledge about the problem would help...

Comment: That should have been your question in the first place, @1LiterTears.

Comment: Hi @MichaelGrant, I edited my question, help it is more clear now. Thanks for your help!

Comment: It is better, yes. Since you're considering a scalar function, you'll want to see [this page](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/Gradient.html), and possibly the [Matrix Cookbook](https://www.google.com/#q=matrix+cookbook), starting with section 2. Note in particular the notation used in the Matrix Cookbook.

Comment: Thank you so much Michael! So basically differentiating a row vector is the same as computing the gradient?

Comment: No. The gradient is a derivative calculation for a scalar-valued function. I think you should worry less about picking apart these individual steps. What you want is the gradient of $x^TAx$: again, read the Matrix Cookbook! It's in there.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Differentiate Row Vectors](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1027048/differentiate-row-vectors)